# When will an idle app be killed on Android

Tags: android

Does Android OS kill idle app after few hours. To be specific, is 12 hours of inactivity of an app warrants an eviction? I understand an idle app get evicted if the phone needs more resources for foreground process. If the phone is just not used and an app goes into background, what is the possibility of it getting killed?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Check how much memory you should use" section in this Android development guide:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html

Each device has a memory level. When the device falls under this level, the system will begin to kill processes.

So to your question... it depends on a number of factors (i.e. if the phone is not actively being used, but has processes running in the background).